# ASCII console - how to handle window resize?

Tags: php, ascii

This is a simple bit of code that draws a green bar almost as long as the screen and write a number at the end, refreshing regularly (the code is in PHP, but its just regular ascii codes):

```
function update($x)
{
    // get the console width
    $width = exec('tput cols');

    // go back up a line if this isn't the first line
    if($x) {
        echo "\033[1A";
    }

    // print a green bar with a number at the end
    echo "\033[42m" . str_repeat(' ', $width - 4) . "$x ";

    // reset formatting and add a new line for next time
    echo "\033[0m\n";
}

for($i = 0; $i < 100; ++$i) {
    update($i);

    // sleep for 0.1 seconds
    usleep(100000);
}
```

When the window is resized larger is fills out the new space as expected, but then you try and shrink the window the layout gets all mangled.

I do not want to reset the whole window, just make sure that line is always the width the console (with the number at the end). Is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

You can register a signal handler for the `SIGWINCH` event. This event will get emitted if the window size changes.

In the signal handler code you'll re-paint the green bar:

```
declare(ticks = 1); 

// Called if the window will get resized
function sig_handler($signo) 
{
    update(123);
}

function update($x)
{

    // Restore Cursor
    echo "\033[u";

    // Erase line
    echo "\033[1K";

    // Get the console width
    $width = exec('tput cols');

    // Go back up a line if this isn't the first line
    if($x) {
        echo "\033[1A";
    }   

    // Print a green bar with a number at the end
    echo "\033[42m" . str_repeat(' ', $width - 4) . "$x ";

    // Reset formatting and add a new line for next time
    echo "\033[0m\n";
}

// Register Signal handler
pcntl_signal(SIGWINCH, "sig_handler");

// Save cursor position
echo "\033[s";

update(123);

// Your program ...
while(true) {
    sleep(1);
}
```

You may follow the [ANSI terminal reference](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/terminalcodes) for the terminal codes I'm using.

Comment: "Call to undefined function pcntl_signal()". I don't understand what "restore cursor" does, if I'm restoring the cursor, why do I still have to move up a line to the original position?

Comment: you need to install the pcntl extension. I'm storing the cursor position before I make any output. When overwriting the green line, I reset the cursor position to its initial value, erase that line and redraw the green line.